# Why getStringSet method of sharedpreferences is not working?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my android app, i am using this line of code:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> set = myPrefs.getStringSet("list", new HashSet<String>());
```

but i am getting following error:

> The method getStringSet(String, HashSet) is undefined for the
>   type       SharedPreferences

Why am i getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getStringSet is available from API Level 11 (Android 3 Honeycomb).

Check which Android version you defined in the project.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set)

Answer (score 2):

`getStringSet()` was added in API Level 11. Your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android) is set to something lower than API Level 11. Please only use this method if you are setting your `minSdkVersion` to 11 or higher.

Comment: I am checking my app at htc wildfire which has android platform 2.2. and its using API level 8. Can i change my API level to 15 and use android platform 2.2? Or do i have to select platform 4.0.3?

Comment: @Piscean: `getStringSet()` does not exist on your Android 2.2 device, no matter how you build your app.

Comment: @Piscean I've made a possible solution for you, if you wish to use.

Comment: Isn't there a way to provide back compatibility?

Comment: @Solace: They did not add `getStringSet()` to `SharedPreferencesCompat`, so there is nothing in Android for backwards compatibility here. You are on your own to do something, such as the `JSONArray` approach shown in another answer on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to support old versions of Android and handle the new APIs. It might even be more efficient (stores less bytes) :

```
  public static void putStringCollection(final Context context,final int prefKeyResId,final Collection<String> newValue)
    {
    final Editor editor=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    final String key=context.getString(prefKeyResId);
    if(newValue==null)
      editor.remove(key).apply();
    else editor.putString(key,new JSONArray(newValue).toString()).apply();
    }

  public static Set<String> getStringSet(final Context context,final int prefKeyResId)
    {
    final String key=context.getString(prefKeyResId);
    final String str=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key,null);
    if(str==null)
      return null;
    try
      {
      final JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(str);
      final Set<String> result=new HashSet<>();
      for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();++i)
        result.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
      return result;
      }
    catch(final JSONException e)
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().remove(key).apply();
      }
    return null;
    }
```

Note: this should be used no matter the API, as it doesn't really convert from/to the new way that Android saves the data.

Comment: Call to `apply()` requires API 9. I get `Call requires API level 9 (current min is 8): android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor#apply`. I would replace it with `commit()` but I have been told that we should never call `commit()` from the UI thread since it works synchronously (while `apply()` is asynchronous). What should I do?

Comment: I have a `string-array` resource in XML, and I am retrieving it in my Activity and using its values to populate a `HashSet`. Now I want to put this HashSet into the SharedPreferences. How do I get the `prefKeyResId` to pass to these methods?

Comment: Are you sure you can't set the minSdk to 9 ? Look at the statistics of people using the Android versions: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html . only 0.1% have  API 8... Anyway, if the data to put isn't too large, it's ok to use commit().

Comment: The "prefKeyResId" is a string resource id of something that's used only as a key for this preference. I do it instead of using strings. You can see in the code that I convert it to a String key. This way I can manage the keys nicely in another file. In order to set the collection into the shared preferences,  use editor.putString(key,new JSONArray(yourCollection).toString()).apply()